# Does Assassins Creed: Unity have unarmed combat?

Tags: assassins-creed-unity

I have have seen the combat system, but I cannot find if you can do hand to hand combat (**Unarmed Combat** or **Fist Fighting**).

**Is it not in the game?**

Comment: please view my answer. You accepted a wrong answer.

Comment: If anyone wants to show me videos of the combat, it would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: @Lokuzt As I stated several weeks ago, please stop asking for users to accept your answers.  It will happen when it happens, and you're quickly drawing close to the annoyance level.  Feedback is optional throughout StackExchange, and continually asking for it doesn't help you at all.  I am going to start flagging the comments for removal quite shortly if you keep it up.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

I think so. From the looks of this screenshot I took https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ystM.jpg, there seems to be two different available weapon selection menus, and what we saw was the "secondary" weapon selection menu, with the phantom blade, smoke bombs, pistol, and medicine (i really hope that isn't coming back).

But you can also see an icon with a sword on it. That's probably the "primary" weapon selection menu where we'll have access to our hidden blade, swords, axes, spears, and of course, fists.

So basically it looks like they're using the system from Revelations and AC3 where you have separate weapon wheels for your main weapons and projectiles/tools, but you don't have to pause what you're doing to change weapons, like what we had in Black Flag.

Comment: -1 because this is plain wrong. You can only select between one-handed (sword), heavy (mace/axe/greatsword), and long weapons (pike/lance). You cannot select Hidden Blades - which are only usable while not in combat - nor can you select fists.

Comment: So you are saying *you* took the screenshot, although your whole post is speculation...

Answer (score 12):

The game does not include **Fist Fighting** (**Unarmed Combat**)

Assassin's Creed Unity does not include many AC Standards like **'Not Being Able to Select hidden Blades'** or **'Fist Fighting'**

List of Removed Mechanics [**here**!](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/948443-AC-Unity-Mechanics?p=10333325) but some are wrong so I'll write down below some major changes in **Unity**.

[EDIT] THere is also [**this IGN page**](http://www.ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-5-unity/Major_Changes_and_Differences) where they give a more reliable source of information about removed and new mechanics.[EDIT]

### General Changes

- You can't whistle in cover like previous games.
- You can't pick up bodies
- No Unarmed Combat
- You just have one weapon instead of choosing between hidden blades, sword and dagger
- You can't use enemies as bullet shields

Here's a [**video of the combat**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=47woYdfeLUQ) even though it doesn't show much you can see that you can only bear one weapon and that weapon is the one selected everytime and you can't choose another. So you can't choose Fists like previous games.

Comment: You might want to look for a more reliable source. A couple of points in that list are wrong. Ledge assassination _is_ possible (there's even a training mission specifically for it) and falling to death as well (I died once falling to my death).

Comment: Please explain the downvote.

Comment: @Lokutz [comments to explain downvotes are never required](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) (I was not the person downvoting, I actually upvoted)

Comment: I know but I would like to know because if there's is ways to improve my answer i would like to know. I think I have a good answer

Comment: Despite saying you should find more reliable source, I gave you a +1 since your answer is essentially correct.

Comment: I added a new link for information. For anyone who might find it useful piece of information

Answer (score 0):

You can not use unarmed combat or use the hidden blades as swords. You have to upgrade your blades using points you gain from completing missions. No new attacks regarding the blades, other than cinematic. It's quite disappointing but think more Hitman: Blood Money - you choose your loadout and your equipment based on stealth, speed or attack and defense, then complete your mission.